# Create an enterprise project and its project site with SharePoint 2016 workflow in Project Server 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, project-server, ms-project

I would like to create a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow to create an enterprise project and its project site on Project Server 2016 if the project request is approved by a supervisor.

Is this possible? if it is, can you please point me to some examples?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can create a PWA site using the workflows as Site collection required higher level of permission which you cant do it from workflows. You need to write some kind of custom solution which will do it for you.

If you have nintex workflows then you can do it: check this blog post: https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/project-site-creation-using-nintex-workflows-2013-based-on-a-enterprise-project-type/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I should have been more clear when I posted my question above. I'm not trying to create a new PWA site on the project server. I'm trying to automate and formalize the project initiation process in an existing PWA application site. I want a workflow to create a new enterprise project on the server based on user's completed answers to PDP pending on the supervisor's approval. Is this possible with SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow? if it is, are there any examples of how to make this happen? Thank you!